# Mongodb indexing error "text contains invalid UTF-8"

Tags: mongodb

```
Whenever am trying to index an collection I get the following error
> db.visits.ensureIndex({rawdata:"text"})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "text contains invalid UTF-8",
        "code" : 28755,
        "codeName" : "Location28755"
}
>
The rawdata contain Email:Time:Url
Am using Mongo / Windows
The data were inserted using mongoimport from 2 tsv files
When I imported the 1st file alone in new collection , indexing was done normally
The second file in new collection raised up the problem again while indexing it
But honestly I can't find the wrong line
Both file contain around +50 million lines
Any help would be appreciated
```

Comment: The underlying cause is a bug in MongoDB whereby Index err msgs may indeed contain invalid UTF-8 characters. Now Fixed in MongoDB 5.1.0: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-50454

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting the non UTF-8 strings to UTF format using 010 editor
still if any one have better sollution , would be welcomed